# Adding Spring support to a JSF Webapp

Tags: spring, hibernate, maven, jsf

I made a really simple JSF webapp and it runs fine.

I then tried to add a Spring/Hibernate entities to manage the business logic and access the database.

The project's build is working fine but the app's run is giving me errors for 3 days.

Here is the setup my latest attempt :

We I have tested with success:
* JSF config (trough a simpler webapp)
* Unit tests on Dao part and Spring part.
The issue is laying in integration of the two worlds.

Server: 
Apache 8.5.24

The pom.xml.
A "Show graph" does not reveal any conflict in dependencies version.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>zparkingb</groupId>
    <artifactId>disquesapp2</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>disquesapp2</name>
    <properties>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <org.springframework-version>3.1.1.RELEASE</org.springframework-version> 
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- JSF + PrimeFace -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>5.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.faces</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.weld.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>weld-servlet-shaded</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Swing + Hibernate -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>   
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.11.Final</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.10</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency> <!--LVR: for the @NotNull, @Size, ...-->
            <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.7.Final</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-copy-resources</id>
                        <phase>process-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <overwrite>true</overwrite>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}/</outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources-webapp-common</directory>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>            
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <url>http://repository.primefaces.org/</url>
            <id>PrimeFaces-maven-lib</id>
            <layout>default</layout>
            <name>Repository for library PrimeFaces-maven-lib</name>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

And the libraries added in the .war:

```
antlr-2.7.7.jar
aopalliance-1.0.jar
classmate-1.3.1.jar
commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
dom4j-1.6.1.jar
hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.5.Final.jar
hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar
hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar
hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar
hibernate-validator-6.0.7.Final.jar
jandex-1.1.0.Final.jar
javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar
javax.faces-2.3.3.jar
jboss-logging-3.1.3.GA.jar
jboss-logging-annotations-1.2.0.Beta1.jar
jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar
jstl-1.2.jar
lib.txt
mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar
primefaces-5.0.jar
spring-aop-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-asm-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-core-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-expression-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-jdbc-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-orm-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-tx-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-web-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
validation-api-2.0.1.Final.jar
weld-servlet-shaded-3.0.2.Final.jar
xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar
```

The META-INF/context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--<Context antiJARLocking="true" path="/disquesapp2"/> LVR: not supported anymore as of Tomcat 8-->
<Context path="/disquesapp2">
    <!-- Utilisation de Weld pour les ManagedBean -->
    <Resource name="BeanManager" 
          auth="Container"
          type="javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager"
          factory="org.jboss.weld.resources.ManagerObjectFactory" />
</Context>
```

The WEB-INF/faces-config.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<faces-config
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_3.xsd"
    version="2.3"
>
    <application>
        <!-- Translation -->
        <resource-bundle>
            <base-name>
                messages
            </base-name>
            <var>msg</var>
        </resource-bundle>

        <!-- This JSF variable resolver lets you reference JSF managed
        beans from a Spring context, or a Spring bean from a managed bean -->
        <variable-resolver>
            org.springframework.web.jsf.DelegatingVariableResolver
        </variable-resolver>
        <locale-config />
    </application>

    <lifecycle />

    <factory />

    <managed-bean>
        <managed-bean-name>requestBean</managed-bean-name>
        <managed-bean-class>
            zparkingb.disquesapp.controler.RequestBean
        </managed-bean-class>
        <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
        <managed-property>
            <property-name>disqueService</property-name>
            <value>#{disqueService}</value>
        </managed-property>    
    </managed-bean>
    <managed-bean>
        <managed-bean-name>changeLocal</managed-bean-name>
        <managed-bean-class>
            zparkingb.disquesapp.controler.ChangeLecal
        </managed-bean-class>
        <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
    </managed-bean>

    <navigation-rule>
        <from-view-id>/index.xhtml</from-view-id>
        <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>showsearch</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/search.xhtml</to-view-id>
        </navigation-case>
        <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>error</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/exception.xhtml</to-view-id>
        </navigation-case>
    </navigation-rule>
    <navigation-rule>
        <from-view-id>/search.xhtml</from-view-id>
        <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>disquedetail</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/disque.xhtml</to-view-id>
        </navigation-case>
        <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>error</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/exception.xhtml</to-view-id>
        </navigation-case>
    </navigation-rule>
    <navigation-rule>
        <from-view-id>/disque.xhtml</from-view-id>
        <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>res</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/search.xhtml</to-view-id>
        </navigation-case>
        <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>error</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/exception.xhtml</to-view-id>
        </navigation-case>
    </navigation-rule>
</faces-config>
```

The WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd 
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd">

    <!-- Initialisation des beans Dao -->
    <bean id="disqueDao" class="zparkingb.disquesapp.dao.DisqueDaoImpl" >
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="editeurDao" class="zparkingb.disquesapp.dao.EditeurDaoImpl">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="disqueService" class="zparkingb.disquesapp.bo.DisqueServiceImpl">
        <property name="disqueDao" ref="disqueDao"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="editeurService" class="zparkingb.disquesapp.bo.EditeurServiceImpl">
        <property name="editeurDao" ref="editeurDao"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Config de la base de données -->
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="location">
            <value>/WEB-INF/properties/database.properties</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource"
          class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${dbconfig.jdbc_driverClassName}" />
        <property name="url" value="${dbconfig.jdbc_url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${dbconfig.jdbc_username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${dbconfig.jdbc_password}" />
    </bean>   

    <bean id="sessionFactory"
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">

        <property name="dataSource">
            <ref bean="dataSource"/>
        </property>

        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <!-- Le dialecte de la db utilisée -->
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${dbconfig.hibernate_dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>

                <!--Indique où doivent tourner les sessions -->
                <!--<prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">jta</prop>-->
                <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</prop>

                <!-- Ajouté de manière à pouvoir peupler les relations LAZY en dehors de la transation-->
                <prop key="hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>

        <!-- Indique quelles classes il faut parser pour trouver les classe d'entités-->
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="zparkingb.disquesapp.jpa" />

    </bean>



    <!-- Transactions management -->
    <!-- TODO : to add later --> 

    <!-- Exception translation -->
    <!--LVR: causes errors => in comments  -->
    <!--<bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />-->
    <!-- persistence -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />

</beans>
```

As such, this is the Apache log file I've got when running:

```
03-Feb-2018 22:56:05.802 GRAVE [http-nio-8085-exec-8] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Exception lors de l'envoi de l'évènement contexte initialisé (context initialized) à l'instance de classe d'écoute (listener) [com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener]
 java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: Factory 'javax.faces.lifecycle.ClientWindowFactory' was not configured properly.
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:315)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4745)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5207)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
...
Caused by: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: Factory 'javax.faces.lifecycle.ClientWindowFactory' was not configured properly.
    at 
    ... 48 more
Caused by: javax.faces.FacesException: Unable to find CDI BeanManager
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.isJsf23(ApplicationImpl.java:2718)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.addELResolver(ApplicationImpl.java:553)
    at javax.faces.application.ApplicationWrapper.addELResolver(ApplicationWrapper.java:611)
    at org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.jsf.WeldApplication.<init>(WeldApplication.java:72)
    ... 51 more

03-Feb-2018 23:04:15.230 INFOS [http-nio-8085-exec-2] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
03-Feb-2018 23:04:18.053 GRAVE [http-nio-8085-exec-2] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Exception lors de l'envoi de l'évènement contexte initialisé (context initialized) à l'instance de classe d'écoute (listener) [com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener]
 java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:315)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4743)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5207)
```

---

The JSF controler:

```
package zparkingb.disquesapp.controler;

import java.util.List;
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.inject.Singleton;
import zparkingb.disquesapp.bo.DisqueService;
import zparkingb.disquesapp.jpa.Disque;
import zparkingb.disquesapp.jpa.Editeur;

/**
 *
 * @author laurent
 */
@Singleton
@Named
public class RequestBean {

    private List<Disque> disques;
    private Disque currentDisque;
    private int currentIndex;
    private Editeur filterEditeur;
    private DisqueService disqueService;

    public Editeur getFilterEditeur() {
        return filterEditeur;
    }

    // Filter
    public void setFilterEditeur(Editeur pFilterEditeur) {
        this.filterEditeur = pFilterEditeur;
    }

    // Disques
    public List<Disque> getDisques() {
        return disques;
    }

    public Disque getCurrentDisque() {
        return currentDisque;
    }

    // Action
    public String searchDisques() {
        if (filterEditeur == null) {
            disques = disqueService.getAllDisques();
        }
        else {
            disques = disqueService.getAllDisques(filterEditeur);
        }
        if (!disques.isEmpty())
            currentDisque = disques.get(0);
        else
            currentDisque = null;

        currentIndex = 0;

        return "";
    }

    public boolean hasNext() {
        return (currentIndex < (disques.size() - 1));
    }

    public boolean hasPrevious() {
        return (currentIndex > 0);
    }

    public String previous() {
        if (currentIndex > 0) {
            currentIndex = 0;
            currentDisque = disques.get(currentIndex);
        }
        return null;
    }

    public String next() {
        if (currentIndex < (disques.size() - 1)) {
            currentIndex++;
            currentDisque = disques.get(currentIndex);
        }
        return null;
    }

    public int getCurrentIndex() {
        return currentIndex;
    }

    public void setCurrentIndex(int pCurrentIndex) {
        this.currentIndex = pCurrentIndex;
    }

    // -- SPRING INJECTION --
    public DisqueService getDisqueService() {
        return disqueService;
    }

    public void setDisqueService(DisqueService pDisqueService) {
        this.disqueService = pDisqueService;
    }

}
```

The main object Service bean:

```
package zparkingb.disquesapp.bo;

import java.util.List;
import zparkingb.disquesapp.dao.DisqueDaoImpl;
import zparkingb.disquesapp.jpa.Disque;
import zparkingb.disquesapp.jpa.Editeur;

/**
 *
 * @author laurent
 */
public class DisqueServiceImpl implements DisqueService {

    private DisqueDaoImpl disqueDao;

    public void setDisqueDao(DisqueDaoImpl pDisqueDao) {
        this.disqueDao = pDisqueDao;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Disque> getAllDisques() {
        return disqueDao.getAllDisques();
    }

    @Override
    public List<Disque> getAllDisques(Editeur pEditeur) {
        return disqueDao.getAllDisques(pEditeur);
    }

    @Override
    public Disque getDisqueById(Integer pId) {
        return disqueDao.getDisqueById(pId);
    }

    @Override
    public Disque getDisqueByName(String pName) {
        return disqueDao.getDisqueByName(pName);
    }

    @Override
    public void save(Disque disque) {
        disqueDao.save(disque);
    }

    @Override
    public void update(Disque disque) {
        disqueDao.update(disque);
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(Disque disque) {
        disqueDao.delete(disque);
    }


}
```

The main object Dao bean

```
package zparkingb.disquesapp.dao;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;
import org.hibernate.Criteria;
import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.criterion.Restrictions;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import zparkingb.disquesapp.exceptions.*;
import zparkingb.disquesapp.jpa.Disque;
import zparkingb.disquesapp.jpa.Editeur;

//@Transactional
public class DisqueDaoImpl implements DisqueDao, Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Disque> getAllDisques() {
        try {
            return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("FROM Disque").list();// "Disque" = le nom de la classe
        } catch (Throwable th) {
            throw new DisquesException(1, th);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public List<Disque> getAllDisques(Editeur pEditeur) {
        try {
            Query query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().getNamedQuery("findDisquesByEditeur").setLong(
                    "idEditeur", pEditeur.getId());
            return query.list();
        } catch (Throwable th) {
            throw new DisquesException(3, th);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Disque getDisqueById(Integer pId) {
        try {
            return (Disque) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get(Disque.class, pId);
        } catch (Throwable th) {
            throw new DisquesException(4, th);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Disque getDisqueByName(String pName) {
        try {

            Criteria crit = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Disque.class);
            crit.add(Restrictions.eq("title", pName));

            return (Disque) crit.uniqueResult();

        } catch (Throwable th) {
            throw new DisquesException(5, th);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void save(Disque disque) {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(disque);
    }

    @Override
    public void update(Disque disque) {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().update(disque);
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(Disque disque) {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().delete(disque);
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you actually try to post the error from the stacktrace in a searchengine... Please do, they make perfect search criteria (effectively three of the tags in the question are totally not related) And offtopic: may I suggest to use JPA... And looking at all your XML config, you are using a prehistoric tutorial...

Comment: And a very old spring xsd config...

Comment: Hello Kukeltje, I keep on using Search engines, but every time I fix one issue, there is another one coming. My troubles come ftom the multitude of tutorials and answers, in this quickly out-of-date domain. So confusing for a newbie. Can you point me to a definitive state-of-the-art 2018 tutorial ? Thanks

Comment: To an extend I agree about the fact that Google sometines does a bad job here and giving number of hits more precedence than the actuality of the article. Posting the error in Google is however working fine. Regarding tutorials, start here https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info and https://jsf.zeef.com but also decide what you want to use: is spring currently relevant/needed or is java-ee as great. Can jpa be used instead of plain hibernate. Is a java-ee Server better/easier to use than a servlet engine... etc...

Comment: Where does your application run? On Tomcat? Ever thought about using Spring Boot? https://dzone.com/articles/developing-jsf-applications-with-spring-boot

Comment: My goal is to do a little POC for a Cloud-hosted WebApp. For now I've chosen Azure, but I'm developing at home on a Tomcat and MySQL. Spring+Hibernate seemed to be a good choice for something made in proper way and for a personal teaching on WebApp world. If this is not the best approach, I can start all over again !! The dzone article on spring-boot is interesting.

Comment: I think Spring and JSF are not really good friends. Why not using a CDI based application? If you want something like Spring-Data maybe take a look at https://deltaspike.apache.org/documentation/data.html which is very similar but fully in the JEE world. Another article I have found is https://www.baeldung.com/spring-jsf, which should address your issue if you want to stay with JSF and Spring. With e.g. wildfly you get all your dependencies you need for a JEE application and if it has to be a standalone service then maybe take a look at https://thorntail.io/ which is based on wildfly.